# How to position the Popup window so that the Top= Top of the text & Left= left of the text + length of the text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, I got this simple html code

```
This is the text <a href="javascript:window.open('abc.html','width=500,height=350')"> 
<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9iz/Gaj/9izGaj9iE.gif" 
alt="show" height="15" width="15" /></a>
```

I want that when user clicks on the image it will show as the following picture:

[image]

I don't like JQuery stuffs, so

**Could you do it using simple javascript code? as less code as possible?**

Answer (score 0):

otherwise you can use popup.js which comes with the Bootstrap package

you can download it from this site
http://getbootstrap.com/
this should work for you.
if you don't know bootstrap just read about it at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp